# Tensorflow terribly slow on Mac Studio M1 Ultra

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, apple-m1

I have a Mac Studio M1 Ultra and I am trying to train a simple RNN to forecast time series.

The code is the following

```
import numpy as np
import keras 
import tensorflow as tf

def generate_time_series(batch_size, n_steps):
    freq1, freq2, offsets1, offsets2 = np.random.rand(4, batch_size, 1)
    time = np.linspace(0, 1, n_steps)
    series = 0.5 * np.sin((time - offsets1) * (freq1 * 10 + 10)) # wave 1
    series += 0.2 * np.sin((time - offsets2) * (freq2 * 20 + 20)) # + wave 2
    series += 0.1 * (np.random.rand(batch_size, n_steps) - 0.5) # + noise
    return series[..., np.newaxis].astype(np.float32)

np.random.seed(42)
n_steps = 50
series = generate_time_series(10000, n_steps + 1)

X_train, y_train = series[:7000, :n_steps], series[:7000, -1]
X_valid, y_valid = series[7000:9000, :n_steps], series[7000:9000, -1]
X_test, y_test = series[9000:, :n_steps], series[9000:, -1]

# Implementing simple RRN
np.random.seed(42)
tf.random.set_seed(42)

model = keras.models.Sequential([keras.layers.SimpleRNN(1, input_shape=[None, 1])])

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adam(learning_rate=0.005)
model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=optimizer)
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=20,
                    validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid))
```

On my Mac M1, I have installed `tensorflow` 2.13.0 following the instructions [here](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) and I have `keras` 2.13.1. Python version is 3.11.

When I run the code, I get the following output during training

```
2023-11-14 17:55:24.172843: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:114] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
Epoch 1/20
219/219 [==============================] - 148s 676ms/step - loss: 0.4310 - val_loss: 0.2155
Epoch 2/20
219/219 [==============================] - 143s 651ms/step - loss: 0.1627 - val_loss: 0.1514
Epoch 3/20
219/219 [==============================] - 142s 649ms/step - loss: 0.1462 - val_loss: 0.1488
Epoch 4/20
219/219 [==============================] - 141s 644ms/step - loss: 0.1474 - val_loss: 0.1475
Epoch 5/20
219/219 [==============================] - 142s 649ms/step - loss: 0.1477 - val_loss: 0.1508
Epoch 6/20
219/219 [==============================] - 142s 649ms/step - loss: 0.1006 - val_loss: 0.0617
...
```

which shows that it takes ~140s per epoch.

however, if I run the same code on Google Colaboratory, I get

```
Epoch 1/20
219/219 [==============================] - 6s 24ms/step - loss: 0.0485 - val_loss: 0.0173
Epoch 2/20
219/219 [==============================] - 3s 13ms/step - loss: 0.0132 - val_loss: 0.0118
Epoch 3/20
219/219 [==============================] - 4s 17ms/step - loss: 0.0119 - val_loss: 0.0113
Epoch 4/20
219/219 [==============================] - 4s 18ms/step - loss: 0.0116 - val_loss: 0.0110
Epoch 5/20
219/219 [==============================] - 5s 23ms/step - loss: 0.0114 - val_loss: 0.0109
Epoch 6/20
219/219 [==============================] - 2s 8ms/step - loss: 0.0114 - val_loss: 0.0109
Epoch 7/20
219/219 [==============================] - 2s 8ms/step - loss: 0.0114 - val_loss: 0.0109
```

which is 100x faster!

Why such a difference?

I have read the tensorflow has some performance problem on Silicon Apple. Is there any way I can reach such performances?

Comment: Have you reviewed the docs on installation of / attempted to use [tensorflow-metal](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/)? (Also see https://blog.tensorflow.org/2021/06/pluggabledevice-device-plugins-for-TensorFlow.html, which has notes on how to determine whether any hardware acceleration is in use).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, I have installed command line tools, `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-metal` as indicated in the docs. The command `tf.config.list_physical_devices()` returns `[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'),
 PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]` so it appears the GPU is recognized.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy if I uninstall `tensorflow-metal` I get 2ms/step . So, the problem seems to be `tensorflow-metal` .  But in this way the GPU is not used at all, indeed it won't be listed in the physical_devices()

Comment: Sounds like something to ask about over on the [tensorflow issue tracker](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues), too.

Comment: The model is too simple for a GPU, you see this as CPU is faster than both Metal and the Collab GPU. You need a much bigger model to profit from GPU acceleration.